# How to color background of Canvas label after it is drawn?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am using Tkinter and need to color the background of a label after it is drawn based on an input value.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font

    
if __name__=='__main__':
    listo=chose_num()
    main_win=Tk()
    main_win.title('Your Bingo Bord')
    rows, cols = (15, 5) 
    arr = [[None]*cols]*rows 

    #Column O
    can1=Canvas(main_win,width=100,height=70,bg='white')
    lab1=Label(can1, text="O", width=10,fg = 'red')
    lab1.pack()
   
    
    main_win.mainloop()
```

Let's say I want to color the background of one of the labels. How can I do this without reconstructing the canvas, please?
How should I approach this, please?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `arr[i][j].config(bg=...)`.

Comment: well. I do this for some reason always the last row of the table gets a green background! I updated the code. I do appreciate the help!

Comment: You initialized `arr` wrong: `arr = [[None]*cols]*rows`.  All the rows will reference to the same array `[None]*cols`. It should be `arr = [[None]*cols for _ in range(rows)]` which will create independent rows.

Comment: @acw1668 Why not provide an answer?

Comment: Thank you so much @acw1668. I suppose the issue was about deep and weak copies in Python. I was wondering how one can debug this? I am using VS code and in the variable/watch it was showing the label objects, etc. Is there a better more debugging tool?